# Sklearn Regression Without Predictors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

Is it possible to run a regression (for example, logistic regression) with and without (i.e., with only the intercept) predictors in sklearn? It seems like a fairly standard type analysis and maybe this information is already available in the output.

The only related thing I've found is `sklearn.svm.l1_min_c` but this returns a non-null model.

I'm looking for something along the lines of this, regression with only intercept (`Y = a + ε`) vs standard regression (`Y = a + bX + ε`): http://www.philender.com/courses/linearmodels/notes1/nopredict.html

Or specifically this (as it's related to logistic regression): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82940/is-the-null-model-for-binary-logistic-regression-just-the-natural-log-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure to get what you mean, but you might be interested in `sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier` and `sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor`, which make predictions using simple rules, such as:

“most_frequent”, “uniform”, “constant”, “mean”, “median”, ...

Otherwise, please reformulate your question to indicate a more specific usecase.

Comment: I've edited my question. I saw the `DummyClassifier` before and didn't think that was what I needed but maybe I need the `constant` method where the constant is just the mean of Y.

Comment: You seem to be interested in regression, and not classification. Be aware that `LogisticRegression`, despite its name, is a classifier and not a regressor.
For a simple regression, look at `LinearRegression` and `DummyRegression` with `strategy=“mean”`

Comment: No, I'm definitely interested in logistic regression as I have a binary response variable. I only wrote the standard regression equation to give a simple example of what I was looking for. For an explicit example of the null mode using logistic regression: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82940/is-the-null-model-for-binary-logistic-regression-just-the-natural-log-function

Comment: but agreed that this `DummyClassifier` is the way to go.

Comment: Agree with the answer, but logistic regression is **not** a classifier, see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22381/why-not-approach-classification-through-regression/22382#22382 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116056/35989, so DummyClassifier with strategy="mean" would result in intercept-only logistic grgression (pred_proba output)

Comment: @Tim `DummyClassifier` does not have `strategy="mean"`

Comment: @Sal I meant DummyRegression

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding a constant feature to the (empty) X so now X is the same as np.ones((X.shape[0],1)). The resulting model have the expected mean as interception_ and coef_ is array([ 0.]).