# How to run regression without predictor?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a regression without predictor, just constant and error term. The model is `y = a + error`.

I have tried as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.normal(size=50)

sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(), missing='drop').fit()
```

However, this does not work.

Comment: What is `sm`? What is `y`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: import statsmodels.api as sm, and y is just an array of numbers.

Comment: Your question has the potential to be useful to this community. However, it doesn't provide much information and context. Please try to clarify what have you try until now.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto, I have clarified as much as I have

Comment: It seems more clear now. Thank you for clarifying your question.

Comment: Have you tried creating an array of the same length as y and giving it a single value (ie: x = [0,0,0,0,0,...])? By treating this as your independent variable, youd have no information gain since the predictor is always the same

Answer (score 0):

As denoted [here](http://www.philender.com/courses/linearmodels/notes1/nopredict.html), using regression without predictors is not a major data analysis tool. Logistic regression is not a classifier, while this was already discussed as "[Linear vs. Logistic Regression on Classification Problems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22382/96646)" and "[Regression for Binary Classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116056/96646)". However, it can still be a requirement for any reason like the one you pointed in this question. Thus, we will try to provide a proper solution as an answer to your case.

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46916062/2371987), you can use [`DummyRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor.html) from [Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.dummy import DummyRegressor

X = np.random.normal(size=50)
y = np.random.normal(size=50)

dummy_regr = DummyRegressor(strategy="mean")
dummy_regr.fit(X, y)

...
```